# How do I stop evaluating an expression in Lisp Interaction mode?

Tags: eval, lisp-interaction-mode

So I made a loop that prints out numbers from 0 - 100,000,000 and it's still going.

How do I force stop it?

I have a feeling that something like this is going to happen again one day..

Comment: C-g works for me.

Comment: That only works sometimes.

Comment: It works fine for me on Emacs 25.3.1 both with by customizations and with emacs -Q.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using emacs-nox and Cygwin. I tried to figure out how to dump the core, but I've never done that before. Seems like a lost cause.

Comment: No idea. I always use the GUI version of GNU Emacs (with toolbars, scrollbars and other gui elements disabled) on Linux